# Linux word processor with good inline Word formula support

Tags: linux, ubuntu, microsoft-word, word-processor

Is there a word processor for Linux, specifically Ubuntu, which has excellent support for Word equations in existing docx documents?

LibreOffice supports viewing and editing equations, but the editing process seems a bit complicated. You can't just type in them; clicking them to edit them opens a new window in which you edit your equation. Ideally I'd like to be able to edit them in-line.

I also like Word's 'LaTeX shortcuts' feature, where LaTeX symbol names such as `\theta` are automatically replaced with actual Unicode symbols.

Are there any Word alternatives for Linux with all of these features?

Comment: Replacing things like `\theta` automatically can be done in Libre Office using `Format -> AutoCorrect` :)